# How to define a Swift protocol that enforces its adopters themselves to conform to an associated type?

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I need to work with objects that not only conform to a protocol, but also expose the type of a *second* protocol which they conform to. (This is for use with NSXPCConnection, where you must configurable not only an object to proxy, but also tell it which protocol should be exposed on that proxied object.)

I tried something like:

```
protocol Conformer where Self : Conformer.P  {
    associatedtype P : Protocol
    static var interface : P {get}
    init(info: String)
}

func exposeOverXPC<T:Conformer>(_ _: T.Type) {
    let c : NSXPCConnection = …

    c.exportedInterface = NSXPCInterface(with: T.interface)
    c.exportedObject = T(info:"foo")
}
```

But it results in an error:

> Associated type 'P' can only be used with a concrete type or generic parameter base

Specifically I want `exposeOverXPC` to only accept objects that:

1. Are initializeable in a particular way
2. Have a static property `interface` which references a protocol
3. Are themselves conformant to said `interface`

It's the last step that I'm getting stuck on, is there any way I can accomplish it?

Comment: Deleting the `where` clause on the protocol should make the code compilable. What should be its role in your design?

Comment: Also note that you can't really conform to a `Protocol` instance, as that's not actually a protocol, it mostly carries information about an Objective-C protocol.

Comment: The where clause was a (failed) attempt to enforce my #3 criteria, making sure that a class is actually conformant to the interface it exposes. You might be on to the core of the issue that Swift doesn't like testing conformance against an instance of `@interface Protocol : NSObject`. Is there a different way to accomplish my three criteria?

Comment: My gut says this isn't possible. Protocol conformance in ObjC is very different than in Swift, and `Protocol` has very little to do with `protocol`. For the purposes of XPC, you can definitely conform to the required protocol without ever formally declaring that fact (and that used to be *really* common through "informal protocols," though less-so now). You just have to respond to the required methods at runtime. That's completely different than Swift's idea of protocols. It's an interesting problem, but I don't know that compile-time enforcement is solvable.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot restrict who conforms to a protocol, that goes against the concept of having protocols in the first place if you think about it. However you can use composed types, Swift4 feature, in your generic parameter in `exposeOverXPC`.

```
protocol Interface {
}

protocol XPCExposable {
    associatedtype P: Interface

    init(info: String)
    static var interface: P { get }
}

func exposeOverXPC<T: XPCExposable & Interface>(_ : T.Type) {
    // 1: T is initializeable in a particular way
    // 2: Has a static property interface which references a protocol
    // 3: Are themselves conformant to said interface
}
```

Yes this constraints `T` to conform to `Interface` and not `P`, your best bet is to make `exposeOverXPC` private/internal and provide `API`s that expect `Interface` subtype. wherever you have access to the `Interface` subtype expose that api. e.g:

**Solution 1**

```
protocol InterfaceSubType: Interface {
    fun test()
}

/// Create as many `API`s as the number of `Interface` subtypes you have.
func exposeOverXPC<T: XPCExposable & InterfaceSubType>(_ : T.Type) {
    exposeOverXPC(T.self)
}

/// set to private, you only want to expose the APIs with `Interface` subtype.
private func exposeOverXPC<T: XPCExposable & Interface>(_ : T.Type) {
    // Impl.
}
```

**Solution 2**

An alternative solution to have a function with parameters whose type is the associated type is to add that api (as static function if you wish) by extending the protocol. You must know all the expected subtypes of `Interface` in this extension.

```
extension XPCExposable {

    static func exposeOverXPC<T>(_ interface: P, _ xpcType: T.Type) where T: XPCExposable {

        // Expected subtype Interface 
        if let subInterface = interface as? InterfaceSubType {
            subInterface.test()
        }

        // Other subtypes here.
    }
}
```

Can be called as:

```
let impl = Impl(info: "")
Impl.exposeOverXPC(Impl.interface, Impl.self)
```

Its an extension on `XPCExposable` so you constrain the caller to be a conformer and the parameter requires `XPCExposable.P` so you're all set. 
Downsides of this solution are:

1. You have two parameters instead of one.
2. It uses `if` conditions, I don't know if thats worth mentioning as downside other than that I'd like to push the first solution as favourite.

Comment: I think this only requires that it conforms to *some* `Interface` protocol, not to `P` specifically.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure you can't do that. I can't even think of how conforming to the associated protocol `P` would look like. Anyway, I've edited my answer with some solutions to add more constraint on `Interface`.